# Difference in matching end of line with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, php-7, php-7.3

Given the code:

```
$my_str = '
Rollo is*
My dog*
And he\'s very*
Lovely*
';

preg_match_all('/\S+(?=\*$)/m', $my_str, $end_words);
print_r($end_words);
```

In PHP 7.3.2 ([XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)) I get the unexpected output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Whereas in [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org), on PHP 7.0.33, I get what I expected:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => is [1] => dog [2] => very [3] => Lovely ) )
```

Why am I getting this difference? Did something change in regular expression behaviour after 7.0.33?

Comment: A useful site for testing if something is a version difference, rather than platform or configuration, is https://3v4l.org In this case [it shows the expected output for all versions](http://3v4l.org/YfSSW) so there is some other difference in your test environments. My guess is something related to Windows vs Unix line-endings.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue when testing the above code. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/YfSSW). That tests 7.1.25 - 7.3.3 and gives the expected results. It even works if you check "eol versions", which tests all versions from 4.3

Comment: Using 7.3.3 via the command line I'm seeing the same failure (empty array).

Comment: I tested through CLI on both 7.3.2 and 7.3.3 on an Ubuntu machine and It still gives me the expected result.

Comment: Interesting indeed ... I'm using Windows FWIW. PHP 7.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2019 21:53:23) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64

Comment: What have I uncovered? ;-) Not sure what to say, except it's definitely happening.

Comment: Try `'~(*ANYCRLF)\S+(?=\*$)~'`

Comment: Not sure what that should do, @WiktorStribiżew, but that produces `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Lovely" } } `

Comment: Yeah, forgot `m`, `'~(*ANYCRLF)\S+(?=\*$)~m'` - it should provide consistent output across versions

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it does. But how to explain the behaviour I found? And what is `(*ANYCRLF)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew bump...

Comment: @Utkanos It is easy: without the PCRE verb, the `$` only matches before an LF symbol. Your line endings are CRLF, so the behavior of `$` must be redefined.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wouldn't call that easy or obvious, but thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the environment you have, the [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) library was compiled without the `PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY` option, and `$` in the multiline mode only matches before the LF symbol and `.` matches any symbol but LF.

You can fix it by using the PCRE `(*ANYCRLF)` verb:

```
'~(*ANYCRLF)\S+(?=\*$)~m'
```

`(*ANYCRLF)` specifies a newline convention: `(*CR)`, `(*LF)` or `(*CRLF)` and is equivalent to `PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY` option. See the [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> `PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY` specifies that any Unicode newline sequence should be recognized.

In the end, this PCRE verb enables `.` to match any character *but* a CR and LF symbols and `$` will match right before either of these two characters.

See more about this and other verbs at [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#pcre):

> By default, when PCRE is compiled, you tell it what to consider to be a line break when encountering a `.` (as the dot it doesn't match line breaks unless in [dotall mode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall)), as well the `^` and `$` anchors' behavior in [multiline mode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#). You can override this default with the following modifiers:
>
> ✽ `(*CR)` Only a carriage return is considered to be a line break
> ✽ `(*LF)` Only a line feed is considered to be a line break (as on Unix)
> ✽ `(*CRLF)` Only a carriage return followed by a line feed is considered to be a line break (as on Windows)
> ✽ `(*ANYCRLF)` Any of the above three is considered to be a line break
> ✽ `(*ANY)` Any Unicode newline sequence is considered to be a line break
>
> For instance, `(*CR)\w+.\w+` matches *Line1\nLine2* because the dot is able to match the *\n*, which is not considered to be a line break. See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/jN2fU8/1).

Comment: How very strange. The only thing I can think is that, when I installed XAMPP, I deselected 'install Perl'. I know PCRE derives from Perl, so could that be what's caused this?

Comment: @Utkanos  I don't believe it had any impact. The issue is with how the PCRE library was compiled. Note PCRE regex library is not the same as the one used in Perl.